# NameError: name 'Profile' is not defined

Tags: python, django

here is my models.py code. im trying to run the python3.8 manage.py migrate command to create the tables for the database but i keep getting this error, what could be the issue here. Profile is a class in the models.py code. if you need another part of my code please ask

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone

class Image(models.Model):
    user  = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null='True', blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'pics/')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)      
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)  
    likes =  models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes', blank=True, )
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField()
    image = models.ForeignKey('Image', on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments',null='True', blank=True )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments',null='True', blank=True )
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)  

class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default='default.png')
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, default="My Bio", blank=True)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="followers", blank=True)
    following = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="following", blank=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the Profile class before defining it. Switch the order of the Comment class and Profile class. Like so:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default='default.png')
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, default="My Bio", blank=True)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="followers", blank=True)
    following = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="following", blank=True)  
    
    
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField()
    image = models.ForeignKey('Image', on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments',null='True', blank=True )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments',null='True', blank=True )
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are *referencing* the `Profile` class before this is constructed. You can make use of a string literal instead:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    # …
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        'Profile',  # ← a string literal
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='comments',
        null='True',
        blank=True
    )
    # …
```

It might also be better to rename the field to `profile`, to make it clear the `ForeignKey` is referencing a `Profile` object, not a `User` object:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    # …
    profile = models.ForeignKey(  # ← rename to profile
        'Profile',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='comments',
        null='True',
        blank=True
    )
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).